How to fix the check-and-set parameter while patching secret on vault
While updating new password on vault with patch function getting ['[ERROR] InvalidRequest: check-and-set parameter did not match the current version, on post https://api.vault.secrets.
vault_client.secrets.kv.v2.patch(path=trimmed_path,secret={secret_key: new_password},mount_point=mount_point)

Sounds like a storage mechanism issue... check_and_set is a feature Consul has, maybe the integrated Raft also has it. I would look at your replication configuration.
